# How to add multiple headers in retrofit responses in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

In my application i want get some data from server and for this i used **retrofit**.
I should add some **Headers** but after run application show me **ForceClose** error!

**ApiServices codes :**

```
interface ApiServices {
    @Headers(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type : application/json"
    )
    @POST("user/get-password")
    fun sendPhoneNumber(@Body body: LoginSendPhoneBody): Single<Response<LoginSendPhoneResponse>>

    @Headers(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type : application/json"
    )
    @POST("addresses")
    fun newAddress(@Header("Authorization") userToken: String, @Body body: NewAddressBody):
            Single<Response<NewAddressResponse>>
}
```

My Retrofit version is **2.5.0** !

In **retrofit** documents i read for set multiple **header** i should use `{}` into **Headers** such as `@Headers({...})` , but after add `{}` show me error and i can't use `{}`!

**Logcat error :**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x20 at 12 in header name: Content-Type 
    at okhttp3.Headers.checkName(Headers.java:261)
    at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:311)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseHeaders(RequestFactory.java:283)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseMethodAnnotation(RequestFactory.java:224)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:161)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:65)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:25)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:168)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
    at $Proxy2.sendPhoneNumber(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.app.data.network.ApiUseCase.getSendPhoneNumber(ApiUseCase.kt:42)
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: this may be dumb, but logcat is complaining about character #12, which (depending on where you start reading it) happens to be the space between "Content-Type" and the ":" symbol.
Try it as "Content-Type:" instead of "Content-Type :"

Comment: @TooManyEduardos, ohhhh yeees :D i should use Content-Type: . thanks dear

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To change

```
"Content-Type : application/json"
```

to

```
"Content-Type: application/json"
```

Just remove the blank after `Content-Type` :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use HeaderMap, same

```
val header = HashMap<String, String>()
    header["Accept"] = "application/json"
    header["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    header["Authorization"] = "userToken"



@POST("addresses")
    fun newAddress(@HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>, @Body body: NewAddressBody): Single<Response<NewAddressResponse>>
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but i add into `newAddress` method, i should add this in all of pages used `newAddress` !

Comment: If you want dynamic headers, you make this

Comment: when I am using this HeaderMap, it is not taking all values, some of them are getting lost . They are missing when seeing through interceptor

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin API interface:

```
 @Headers(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "User-Agent : PostmanRuntime/7.29.0",
        "Accept : */*",
        "Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, br",
        "Connection : keep-alive"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use your methods like this:

```
 fun callLoginAPI(@HeaderMap header: Map<String, String>)
```

While calling this method just create the map add all the headers